# Am getting the error when i tried to start the python server in collectd servcie in ubuntu machine?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I installed collectd in my ubuntu machine. Python server is installed by default. I need to push all my system metrics to browser using collectd. For that i need to run python server. But when i tried to run am getting the error.

Please help me.

Below is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import CGIHTTPServer
import BaseHTTPServer
from optparse import OptionParser

class Handler(CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler):
    cgi_directories = ["/cgi-bin"]

PORT = 8888

def main():
    parser = OptionParser()
    opts, args = parser.parse_args()
    if args:
        httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer((args[0], int(args[1])), Handler)
        print "Collectd-web server running at http://%s:%s/" % (args[0], args[1])
    else:
        httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(("127.0.0.1", PORT), Handler)
        print "Collectd-web server running at http://%s:%s/" % ("0.0.0.0", PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When i run the command `python runserver.py`

Am getting output like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runserver.py", line 24, in <module>
    main()
  File "runserver.py", line 19, in main
    httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(("127.0.0.1", PORT), Handler)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 417, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 108, in server_bind
    SocketServer.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 431, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
[1]+  Exit 127                runserver.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can clearly see from the error `Address already in use`. That means you already have some other program which is listening to specified interface / port.

Ensure that no other program is listening to your port (8888). You can do it this way:

```
netstat -plnt | grep 8888
```

and stop the process.

Otherwise change the port number. Please also note, that in order to use port number < 1024, you need root permission. For ports > 1024 you don't need it.

Comment: Thank u it worked....cheers!!!